# Represent Bivariate Normal Vector as Linear Function of Two Independent Standard Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am provided that $X = (X_1, X_2) \sim \mathcal{N}_2(\mu, \Sigma)$, where
$$ \mu = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\
 -2 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\
 -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $$
and I am tasked with expressing $X$ as a linear function of two independent standard random variables, but I am not entirely sure how to do so. From the provided information, it is clear that $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(3,2)$ and $X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(-2,2)$ with $\text{Cov}(X_1, X_2) = -1$. My first attempt was to rewrite the characteristic function associated with this random vector to parse out the independent parts:
\begin{align*}
\phi_X(u) 
&= e^{i \mu^T u - \frac{1}{2} u^T \Sigma u } \\
&= e^{ i(3u_1 - 2u_2) - u_1^2 + u_1 u_2 - u_2^2 } \\
&= e^{ (3i u_1 - u_1^2) + (-2i u_2 - u_2^2) + u_1 u_2  }
\end{align*}
However, the term $u_1 u_2$ (representing the covariance between $X_1$ and $X_2$) in this expression causes my method to fail.

I know that I want to define two random variables, say $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, with $\text{Cov}(Y_1, Y_2) = 0$ such that $X = (X_1, X_2) = aY_1 + bY_2$, where $a$ and $b$ are some constants, but I am unsure how to determine these random variables. Is there some way to factor this above characteristic function expression to get the desired result, or should I approach this using a different method?

**EDIT:** Using the comment from William M., this is what I have so far:

Through eigen-decomposition, we may write $\Sigma = V D V^{-1}$ where $V$ is the matrix of eigenvectors and $D$ is the matrix of eigenvalues. We find that
$$ V = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad D = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} $$
Then, to express $\Sigma$ as $\Sigma = A A^T$, take
$$ A = V \sqrt{D} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \sqrt{3} \\
 1 & -\sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix} $$
and so
$$ A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{2} \\
 \tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} & -\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix} $$
Then,
$$ Y = \begin{bmatrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2 \end{bmatrix} = A^{-1} (X - \mu) =  \begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{2} \\
 \tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} & -\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X_1 - 3 \\
 X_2 + 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \left( \frac{X_1 + X_2 - 1}{2} \right) \\
 \left( \frac{X_1 - X_2 - 5}{2 \sqrt{3}} \right) \end{bmatrix} $$
has zero mean and the identity matrix $I$ as its dispersion matrix. Finally, we may represent $X$ as
$$ X = AY + \mu $$
as desired.

Comment: If $A A^\intercal = \Sigma,$ then $A^{-1} (X - \mu)$ has zero mean and dispersion matrix  $A^{-1} \Sigma A^{-\intercal} = ...$

Comment: @WilliamM. I think I see what you're getting at. The dispersion matrix you have written should be the identity $I$. To find the matrix $A$ as you have written, I found the eigen-decomposition of $\Sigma = V D V^T$ and then set $A = V \sqrt{D}$ (taking the square roots of the eigenvalues in $D$). Following this described method, I am able to find $X = (Y_1, Y_2)$ with $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ independent, but not as a linear function of the two. From there, would I try to do the characteristic function approach again?

Comment: Once you have $Y = A^{-1}(X - \mu)$ is standard normal, then $X = AY + \mu.$

Comment: @WilliamM. Okay, that makes sense, thank you for your help! I have made edits to my original post to reflect what you have said.

Comment: @WilliamM. Does this method also work for when $A$ is singular? I am working on a similar problem now, but $A$ is singular so I was thinking of finding the generalized inverse $A^-$ to obtain $Y = A^- (X - \mu)$.

Comment: $A$ is singular if and only if $\Sigma$ is singular if and only if there exists a subspace $V$ of dimension $\mathrm{rk}(\Sigma)$ such that $P(X \in V) = 1$ if and only if some entries of $X$ are linear cominations of the others. So, you will be able to write $X = DX_0$ with $X_0$ having a non-singular $\Sigma$ and $A.$